# acceder a una subcoleccion de firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, typescript

Tengo una coleccion llamada "routes" la cual tiene una subcoleccion llamada "points" por cada registro. Como puedo obtener los datos de "lat" y "lng" que ahi se encuentran?. Tengo implementado este codigo pero no logro acceder a dichos datos que mencione (lat, lng). Se los agradezco de antemano.

```
`
this.locationsCollection = this.afDB.list('/Marker');    
this.location = this.locationsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({
        key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val().points
    })))
)
    
this.location.subscribe(location => {
    console.log(location)      
    const points = location.map(item => {
        return { lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng}        
    });
    this.updateMap(points);      
})
`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que después de `points` como se aprecia en la imagen, tienes una clave autogenerada. Me pregunto por qué, eso lo único que hace es dificultar el acceso a `lat` y a `lng`, porque necesitarás conocer esa clave para entrar en el nodo. Revisa cómo estás guardando los datos y evita que esa clave se genere, metiendo `lat` y `lng` como hijos directos de `points`. Con la clave autogenerada que es padre de `points` bastaría para identificar los datos de forma única. Simplemente estás creando una estructura complicada sin necesidad.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Sabes, es curioso porque hice el mismo codigo, pero en este agregue una ruta especifica como "Marker/-MQzgu8dHjlV5LLfnHm8" en this.afDB.list . Y en este caso si funcionó. Aunque solo me mostro una sola ruta. En la parte de abajo adjunto el mismo codigo, pero con lo que te mencione.

Comment: Entiendo... Pero una pregunta, ¿lo que hay en las claves autogeneradas son valores de otros puntos: `lat, lng, timestamp`? Si es así, retiro lo dicho en mi anterior comentario. Habrá que buscar una forma de iterar, si quieres sacar todos los valores. ¿Podrías decir qué muestra esto: `console.log(location)`?

Comment: Si amigo. Esas claves que se generan, contienen diferentes coordenadas, las cuales las estoy usando para poder dibujar una linea en una aplicacion que tiene un mapa. Y bueno como te comente anteriormente, solo me funciona cuando especifico una sola ruta. Y lo que quiero, es poder listar todas para dibujar el resto de lineas.

Comment: Ok. En ese caso tendrás que recorrer todos los objetos usando un bucle o algo parecido. Lamentablemente no uso Firebase con ¿Angular? y no podría decirte cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias de igual forma por tu sugerencia amigo. Y si, tambien he tratado de implementar un bucle, pero el formato de los datos me aparece muy diferente a al formato de los datos que tengo en la solucion para mostrar una sola ruta.

Answer (score 0):

En este codigo, puedo acceder a lat y lng. Pero el problema es que solo funciona cuando ingreso una ruta especifica.

```
showRoutes(){
this.locationsCollection = this.afDB.list('/biciruta/-MQtihU8VEm2XqXYYiWa/points/');
this.location = this.locationsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes => 
      changes.map(c => ({
        key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
      })))
)

this.location.subscribe(location => {
  console.log('nueva locacion: ', location);
  this.updateMap(location);
})
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]